# is there any chance of arrest if i carry laptop with NSA Sticker to USA?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, electronic-items, denial-of-entry

Myself planning trip by coming week to Portland,USA. I carry laptop with a sticker "NSA Monitoring device". Is there any chance for getting arrested or refusing visa at transit due to the sticker.

[image: Sample image which was placed over at My laptop]

the sample image which placed above on my laptop was similar.My friends scares me that i might be arrested for that,Anyone faced situation like this before?Looking forward community suggestions.

Note : The obvious solution would be skipping laptop which i am thinking as last choice,Looking forward from fellow travelers for best advice.Also please refer laws incase of any reference to it.Thanks

Comment: Legality aside, this is just a stupid idea. Don't antagonize immigration and customs officials. Their job is already hard enough as it is.

Comment: You could get a bigger sticker and put it over this sticker.

Comment: If you want to be perfectly safe, don't bring this sticker. But it is very unlikely that you will be asked to show your laptop anyway.

Comment: isn't it like wearing a FBI tourist t-shirt?

Comment: You can even go to the [NSA museum and gift shop](https://www.nsa.gov/about/cryptologic-heritage/museum/) and buy a jacket with the NSA logo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrest? No.

Understand, however, that there is a CBP policy that they can search your electronic devices. As in they will demand you unlock your device and let them search (likely copy) the data on your device(s), and will detain you until you do. [That inexplicably happened to a NASA engineer](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2017/02/a-nasa-engineer-is-required-to-unlock-his-phone-at-the-border/516489/).

If I were you, I'd avoid poking that bear. Someone in CBP might see the sticker and demand a search. If you object, they'll point to the sticker and say "Well, you claim it's already been searched..."